# Error while loading MNIST database in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mnist

I'm trying to work with MNIST handwritten digits database but the below two lines are giving me error. Where am I going wrong??

```
from sklearn import datasets
dataset = datasets.fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
```

The error which I am getting is as followed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/HWrecognition/deep-belief-network-gpu-update/kk.py", line 5, in <module>
    dataset = datasets.fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\mldata.py", line 142, in fetch_mldata
    mldata_url = urlopen(urlname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 429, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 605, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1173, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1148, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Comment: Your code works for me, looks like some network-level problem.

Comment: Any suggested troubleshooting technique??

Comment: Maybe you are using proxy?

Comment: Nope... I am not using a proxy

Comment: Then i don't know, sorry, maybe you should google for this error, because this error comes from urllib2